# Different Layout for certain pages in NextJS

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

I'm using Next.js and I want to have a header and a footer on every page of my app, except for the Login page. I've already created a `layout.tsx` file in the app directory, which works fine for applying the layout to all pages. However, when I create a `layout.tsx` file inside the Login directory, the header disappears but the footer remains, and I get three warnings about errors while hydrating.

My LoginPage looks like this:

```
'use client'
import Image from 'next/image'
import LoginLayout from "./layout";
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

function Login() {
    const router = useRouter();

    function checkIfCredentialsAreValid() {


        router.push("/dashboard")

    }

    return (
        <main className="flex p-40 ms-8 justify-center place-items-center">
            <div>
                <Button color="dark" style={{ backgroundColor: "#333", color: "#fff" }} onClick={checkIfCredentialsAreValid}>
                    Anmelden
                </Button>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}

Login.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactNode) {
    return <LoginLayout>{page}</LoginLayout>;
}

export default Login;
```

The code for my layout.tsx is this:

```
import '../globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })


export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}


export default function Layout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html >
  )
}
```

And my File structure looks somewhat like this:

```
-app
 |-login
    |-layout.tsx
    |-page.tsx
  (other Pages after the same sceme)
  |-global.css
  |-layout.tsx
  |-page.tsx
```

I'd appreciate any help on how to properly apply the layout to all pages except for the Login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For everyone coming around this Issue in the future:**

I just renamed the `layout.tsx` to something like `rootLayout.tsx` so nextJS ignores it, then I importet the RootLayout to the sub pages via import `RootLayout from '../rootLayout';` and just implemented the Root Layout when I needed it. So the Code for the Page with a Header looks like this:

```
<RootLayout>
  <main>
    //Content
  </main>
</RootLayout>
```

If you dont want the Layout, just dont use the RootLayout Tag

This way the Root Layout gets rerendered every Time you reload the Page or go to another SubPage. To prevent this, just import the RootLayout like this:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const RootLayout = dynamic(
    () => import('../rootLayout'),
    { ssr: false }
);
```

Comment: A Better solution would have been to just Create a Componement but ig it works this way to